# Why the function doesn't see the "NULL" character

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that will allocate memory for a new character to be read until the null character is read, but it doesn't seem to work

The printf on the line that is commented (after the while loop condition) shows me what value the c+i points at, I just checked and even if it shows me the character NULL (it just prints '--  --', I assume this is the character NULL?) the loop keeps going.

```
char *read(char *c) {

    int i=0;

    c=(char*)malloc(1);
    scanf("%c", c+i); 

    while (*(c+i)) {
        //printf("-- %c --", *(c+i));

        i++;
        c=(char*)realloc(c,i+1);
        scanf("%c", c+i);
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *NULL character*?

Comment: "_I assume this is the character NULL?_". Why do you assume and blind-guess? You can just printf out the ordinal value of the character by using the %d format specifier instead of %c. Then you will _see_ what character you got there, no matter whether the character itself is printable or not...

Comment: Why are you ignoring `scanf()`'s return value? How can you tell when there's an error or if it's attempted to read past the end of input if you don't do that?

Comment: Also, `getchar()` and friends are a better choice if you're reading a character at a time. `scanf()` is overkill for that.

Comment: One other point that nobody else is bringing up.  malloc() without free in the same function is not a good pattern so only do it if and when you must.  It lends itself to memory leaks.  There are better patterns to accomplish this same behavior howbeit at the cost of cycles.  For instance, caller calls function to find out how much to allocate.  Caller allocates buffer and calls back in with allocated buffer.  Then there is a CLEAR CONTRACT of who will free the memory.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` / `calloc()` / `realloc()` in C. It's unnecessary and potentially hides the serious error of a missing prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't stop because it never reads a `NULL` character. When you press a key like RETURN/ENTER the console generates a newline sequence (which is "`\n`" in some operating systems like Linux or "`\r\n`" on some others like Windows).

Having that said, you could then alter your `while` condition to check if the read character is `'\n'` or `'\r'` to end the reading, instead of checking if it was `NULL`. This solution would **stop the reading** as soon as the user presses the return key, though.

Comment: Wow it worked, o my glob thanks so much this thing gave me headaches. I assumed the null character is added automatically as you press enter but if it generated just a new line do you know how to add the NULL character at the end of the string ? Or you can't do that in the console?

Comment: It can definitelly be done: you just have to `realloc()` again to add one new character to your string and set that character to `NULL`, doing this right after your `while (...) {...}` loop.

Comment: I meant if you can add the NULL character from the console after you typed what you wanted to be read, but if the new line is generated automatically i guess it would be pretty pointless, as you can just add it after the while loop ends as you said.

Comment: As I understand it, `NULL` is never generated on a read operation using `scanf()` with specifier `%c` to read the standard input device ("keyboard"). That is because the `%c` specifier reads a character, and `NULL` works not like a character, but as a sort of "placeholder" for representing "no character". Summary: `%c` does not translate any user (keyboard) input to null, ever.

Comment: For the long answer on what is considered a new line, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline. Also, one should be able to handle EOF before new-line gracefully.